# Project Euler - 34 / Find a mathematical approach for upper bound

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, project-euler

> 145 is a curious number, as 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145. 
> Find
>   the sum of all numbers which are equal to the sum of the factorial of
>   their digits. 
> Note: as 1! = 1 and 2! = 2 are not sums they are not
>   included.

So I tried a random enough large upper bound (`100000`) in my program and it worked.

<del>I deleted this part to not spoil the answer</del>

My question is : How to find the closest upper bound using a mathematical approach ?

Comment: by "closest upper bound", do you mean $40585$?

Comment: Is it really viewed as appropriate to come here with PE questions? Include me out.

Comment: @Jonathan No, an upper bound not too big would be enough. Just to know how to search one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Project Euler

Comment: @IgorRivin What's the problem with this question ?

Comment: The problem is that project euler is FOR YOU TO FIGURE OUT. Getting other people to do it defeats the purpose completely.

Comment: @IgorRivin Since I ALREADY find the solution, I don't see where is the problem. I just want to know how to find an upper bound mathematically, not by trying some bounds randomly. Finding an upper bound won't solve the problem for the others (and if you're too lazy to find the solution yourself, googling project euler problem 34 and you'll find plenty of answer in blogs).

Comment: OK, you are right, I withdraw my objection.

Comment: @IgorRivin I deleted the relevant parts to not spoil the answer.

Comment: Excellent idea!

Comment: @IgorRivin There is a [tag:Project-Euler] tag--that is not reason enough to be off topic.  There is extensive discussion about PE on meta...  Truly, it is appropriate to come here with PE questions.

Comment: @anorton interesting. I did NOT know that.

Comment: @IgorRivin, see my answer, correspondence with Project Euler moderator. They really do not want this. People put all sorts of variations, leave out parts, whatever. The part about experimenting on your own has not sunk in...

Comment: @IgorRivin, plus, to my dismay, there are plenty of people of the answering classes who think such questions are fine, sometimes even resent PE's attempts to keep a type of privacy. I will never understand.

Comment: @WillJagy I think that the problem is that the answering classes are highly diverse, and a lot of the members thereof are underachievers who want to convince the rest of us that they can do calc-1 homework (or little contest problems), greater good be damned. I wish I knew what to do about this.

Comment: @Igor, there is something to that. However, some of the moderators, quite strong themselves, feel roughly the same way as a point of policy. So, diversity on top of diversity. When I notice these, I post my letter from hk, that way I do not wind up arguing, in comments, with an endless supply of high school or college kids.  Sometimes I am first, before anyone supplies a substantial answer, but usually not.

Comment: @WillJagy I am sure you are right, but my two weeks (or whatever) on MSE has convinced me of the relative wisdom of the more selective MO model -- the signal-to-noise ratio on MSE is SETI-level. I find it amazing that the diversity advocates have not remarked this also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the sum of the factorials of the digits of $n$. I apologize that this answer is not mathematically rigorous; the purpose is more to give my ideas rather than to prove.

Since $9!=362880$ is six digits, we can expect a seven digit number to have $P(n)$ at most seven digits (Note: $P(9999999) = 2540160$ is seven digits).

Similarly, An eight digit number will yield at most a seven digit $P(n)$. So once we reach eight digits, it is no longer possible. More precisely, anything above $2540160$ is impossible, since this is the highest $P(n)$ we can get with seven digits.

The highest $P(n)$ we can get with $n < 2540160$ is $2177281$ with $n = 1999999$. So we can use $2177281$ as our best bound. We can use this strategy again by checking the second highest $P(n)$ with $n$ under the bound, and so on. But the presented bound, $2177281$, is not out of the realm of computation by any means.

Perhaps more clever arguments yield better bounds. My method turns into raw computation fairly quickly. On the other hand, some of the numbers just under two million seem fairly valid guesses. This leads me to believe there is not an obvious way to reduce my bound below two million.

edit:
I am looking at it further, and it seems like an argument could reasonably reduce my bound under a million. It seems that in order to get $P(n)$ close to two million while using numbers just under two million, we need a lot of $9$s as digits. So it seems that there are very few candidates, few enough to reasonably check by hand, just under two million.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorion) explains how to get some trivial bounds.

The most trivial one is to note that if the number $n$ has $d$ digits, we have

$$10^{d-1}<n<9!d$$ which yields that $d\leq7$ and thus gives an upper bound of $10^7=10000000$.